# Can helm filter files by mode

Tags: helm

I know I can use ibuffer to filter available buffers by mode, but I can I do something analogous directly in helm? The mode is listed by helm, so maybe there is a way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`helm-mini` states in its help (which can be accessed with `C-c ?` while it's running) that a token prefixed with `*` is interpreted as substring match of a major mode.  Therefore, entering `*org` gives you `org-mode` buffers, entering further space-separated tokens can be used to narrow those down even more.